# Limit number of connections to a rabbit queue?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I use `pika-0.10.0` with `rabbitmq-3.6.6` broker on ubuntu-16.04. I designed a Request/Reply service. There is a single Request queue where all clients push their requests. Each client creates a unique Reply queue: the server pushes replies targeting this client to this unique queue. My API can be seen as two messages: `init` and `run`.

`init` messages contain big images, thus `init` is a big and slow request. `run` messages are lighter and the server reuses previous images. The server can serve multiple clients. Usually client#1 `init` then `run` multiple times. If client#2 comes in and `init`, it will replace the images sent by client#1 on the server. And further `run` issued by client#1 would use wrong images. Then I am asking:

- **is it possible to limit the number of connections to a queue?** E.g. the server serves one client at a time.
- another option would be: the server binds images to a client, saves them, and reuse them when this client *runs*. It requires more work, and will impact performance if two or more clients' requests are closely interleaved.
- sending the images in each *run* request is not an option, would be too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem in your design. Logically each `run` corresponds to a certain `init` so they have to be connected. I'd put a correlation id field into `init` and `run` events. When server receives `run` it checks if it there was  a corresponding `init` processed and uses the result of that `init`.

Speaking of performance:
You can make `init` worker queue and have multiple processing servers listen to it. The example is in the [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)
Then, when init request comes in, one of available servers will pick it up, and store your images and the correlation ID. If you have multiple `init` requests at the same time - no problem, they will be processed eventually (or simultaneosly if servers are free)

Then server that did the process sends reply message to the client queue saying `init` work is done, and sends name of the queue where `run` request have to be published.

When ready, client sends its `run` request to the correct queue.

**To directly answer the question:**

there is a common misconception that you publish to a `queue`. In RabbitMQ you publish to an `exchange` that cares about routing of your messages to a number of queues. So you question really becomes `can I limit number of publishing connections to an exchange`. I'm pretty sure there is no way of doing so on the broker side. 
Even if there was a way of limiting number of connections, imagine the situation:

1. Client1 comes in, pushes its 'init' request.
2. Client1 holds its connection, waiting to push `run`.
3. Client1 fails or network partition occurs, its connection gets
   dropped.
4. Client2 comes in and pushes its `init` request.
5. Client2 fails
6. Client1 comes back up and pushes its `run` and gets Client2's
   images.

Connection is a transient thing and cannot be relied upon as a transaction mechanism.

Comment: that's a good-looking solution for bullet #2 indeed. Still, do you know if it is possible to limit the number of connections to a queue?